# Shiny Uploading a CSV File and Graphing Data based on an Input

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to give my Shiny Web App the functionality for someone to upload a `.csv` file to Shiny, and then have the ability to choose (Watts, Amps or Volts) from that `.csv` file to graph with a line graph based on the Select Input.  The Select Input choices should change based on the column headers in the `.csv` file (like doing: `names(file)`).  My data set is here: [CSV Data Set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzg7bDcyZobbQ1RqTmpUSFVQMGM/view?usp=sharing)

My code so far is as follows.  My `ui.R` is okay, I just need some help doing the `server.R`.  I don't really care which plot is graphed, as long as the `Select Input` changes based on the headers of the file that is uploaded.  I have used `Dygraph`, but there may be a better line graph out there.

## ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Engineering Data",
        tabPanel("Data Set",
column(5, offset = 1,   
                  fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                     accept = c(
                       'text/csv',
                       'text/comma-separated-values',
                       'text/tab-separated-values',
                       'text/plain',
                       '.csv',
                       '.tsv'
                     )
           ),
           
     #File Upload for Shiny Framework
     tags$hr(),
     checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
     radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                  c(Comma=',',
                    Semicolon=';',
                    Tab='\t'),
                  ','),
     selectizeInput("channel", label = "Choose a Channel",
                    choices = NULL)),
  # Graph Output
  fluidRow(
    column(12, some_graph_output("chart")
    ))
```

## server.R

I need some help with this...

Comment: Check out this answer  --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980530/dynamic-options-for-dropdown-menu-in-shiny-r-with-html-ui/26981706#26981706  --  It allows you to pick the columns you want to work with.